# All channel entries have had their statuses changed to 'closed'

Tags: mysql

It looks like one of my sites has been compromised with an SQL injection. All the channel entries have been closed, which amounts to over 5k entries.

I restored the database with a previous daily backed, so all is well again, but have no idea what could have caused this, seems most likely to be a rogue sql query as no way to accidentally change all open statuses to closed in the CP.

I have added in extra security by changing passwords, system directory name, removed some add-ons, switched XSS filter back, check permissions, etc.

The site's still on 1.7 and Ellislab have had a look around the CP and say they can't see any evidence of a virus.

I'd be very interested to hear if anyone has had a similar experience.

Comment: Do you have the Structure module installed?

Comment: Any custom add-ons? Any cron jobs which call an EE action?

Comment: Not using Structure, the add-ons being used are Cartthrob, User, Wygwam, Freeform, Better Meta, Form Helper, Stand-alone member edit, LinkLocker.

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember this happening to a friend of mine and it was a Cartthrob issue rather than a compromise. Let me try to nudge him in the direction of this thread.

Comment: I doubt its been compromised. Any add-on messing with statuses could easily botch up the entries with a bad query or php logic. Also make sure that the channels have a status group assigned to them that contains an "open" status. If EE can't find an open status, or the channel does not have a status group assigned at all, it will default to closed.

Answer (score 1):

He's not a SE user so I'll answer this for him here. Apparently he had the same issue and it was down to a bug with maestro payments. Does that sound like it might be it?

CT gave him a patch to fix it so you should contact them.

Comment: I'll see if I get support off Cartthrob on this, and will post back if get any news.

Answer (score 1):

Questions: What payment gateway are you using?

NOTE:  If it is related to CT, and CT did indeed close ALL entries, it would most likely be some situation where we have a channel entries call to close a specific entry, but without a limit set on it… and a channel entry id was not passed in the call to close the entry.

Over time, I have seen cases where my add-on or other similar add ons would close a junk load of entries if a limit was not set on the close call and the ID passed in was null or blank.

If indeed it was a CT problem, that's where I'd start looking… Most likely culprit would be a bad callback with missing data and a gateway file with a call to close an entry with no limit set, or something in the core itself calling to close an entry based on some condition hit without an entry id.

In CT2 I know I've gone on hunting expeditions for this kind of thing to make sure it wouldn't happen, but I have not gone through the same process for 1.7

Comment: Answer: RBS Worldpay Redirect Payment Gateway - where do I look to limit the callback to one entry?

Comment: I know an upgrade to CT2 is always recommended, and I'd be doing it right now if I had the time, so if a hot fix or even a 'might help' fix comes to mind, please let me know - thanks.

Comment: Because the solution may be fairly complex to test and evaluate I suggest you schedule a Phone/Skype appointment with the CartThrob/Mightybigrobot support team at http://support.mightybigrobot.com. A member of our support team can speak with your personally and will custom tailor a suitable solution to this issue.